# Javascript get select value inside two divs

Tags: javascript, html

In my project i have a select  incapsulated into two divs, i have to get the text or value) from the select from a javascript.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6" id="div1">
      <div class="form-group" id="divTtype">
          <label>Templte Type:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="ftype">
              <option value="..All">..All</option>
              <option value="Functional">Functional</option>
              <option value="Non Functional">Non Functional</option>
          </select>
        </div>
 </div>
```

i try this code:

```
function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(childID);
    var parent = elm ? elm.parentNode : {};
    return (parent.id && parent.id === containerID) ? elm : {};
}
```

but when i try :

```
GetElementInsideContainer(divType, ftype).text;
```

an "undefined" return to me.

How can i get my select value?

so many thanks in advance

Comment: Cant you directly select the select tag with `ftype` id? `document.getElementById("ftype")`?

Comment: No, always "undefined" is the response i get

Comment: Don't you mean like this: https://codepen.io/shamshoum/pen/rbgWXP see console

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's a typo in your HTML code "divTtype", you meant to write divType

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6" id="div1">
    <div class="form-group" id="divType">
        <label>Templte Type:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="ftype">
            <option value="..All">..All</option>
            <option value="Functional">Functional</option>
            <option value="Non Functional">Non Functional</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you need to use `textContent` attribute instead of `text`

Finally please call the function using `"id"`, else you are calling undefined variables `divType` and `ftype`

```
console.log(GetElementInsideContainer("divType", "ftype"));
```

---

This will certainly fix your current issue, although please refer to raphael answer for better approach.

Comment: @Plastic Oh cool, it does not matter who gets to answer it. What matters we, the community, get to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Because text doesn't exist into HTMLElement.
You have to do this:

```
GetElementInsideContainer(divType, ftype).textContent;
```

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Answer (score 1):

You should use quotes when you send string as a parameter:

```
GetElementInsideContainer('divType', 'ftype').text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Krishna said in the comment above, you should be able to just do:

```
var select = document.getElementById('ftype')
var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
```

You don't have to reference the parent node.

Answer (score 1):

> Use **textContent** and pass id in form of **string** otherwise it take it as a variable
>
> secondly you have id **divTtype** and you were passing **divType**

```js
function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(childID);
  var parent = elm ? elm.parentNode : {};
  return (parent.id && parent.id === containerID) ? elm : {};
}


var a = GetElementInsideContainer("divType", "ftype").textContent;
console.log(a)
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6" id="div1">
  <div class="form-group" id="divType">
    <label>Templte Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="ftype">
      <option value="..All">..All</option>
      <option value="Functional">Functional</option>
      <option value="Non Functional">Non Functional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine overhere.

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6" id="div1">
      <div class="form-group" id="divTtype">
          <label>Templte Type:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="ftype">
              <option value="..All">..All</option>
              <option value="Functional">Functional</option>
              <option value="Non Functional">Non Functional</option>
          </select>
        </div>
 </div>
 <button onclick="getSelected(GetElementInsideContainer('divTtype', 'ftype'))">Get Selected Value</button>
 <script>
 function getSelected(objEl)
 {
  alert(objEl.options[objEl.selectedIndex].text);
 }
 
function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(childID);
    var parent = elm ? elm.parentNode : {};
    return (parent.id && parent.id === containerID) ? elm : {};
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

do you need the selected value of the select?

I did that snippet and get the HTML of the select.
with this snippet, you can get the value of a select

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6" id="div1">
      <div class="form-group" id="divTtype">
          <label>Templte Type:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="ftype">
              <option value="..All">..All</option>
              <option value="Functional">Functional</option>
              <option value="Non Functional">Non Functional</option>
          </select>
        </div>
 </div>
```

```
function GetElementInsideContainer( childID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(childID);
    console.log(elm.value)
    return elm.value;
}
GetElementInsideContainer('ftype');
```

I think that maybe you pass in the argument an incorrect id